# In Umbraco 8 How do I query and return only nodes that appear in a tag list?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, umbraco

I have a product section with hundreds of product nodes. Each has a product code. I have created a document type that allows an editor to create their own bespoke category list page by giving the category a name and content and then a list of products that should appear under it called 'productList'.

The pseudo-code is below to give an idea of what I am looking for but I have tried different ways and come up with nothing that works.

```
**var selection = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse(theGUID))
.ChildrenOfType("product")
.Where([PRODUCTCODE IS IN TAGLIST 'productList'])
.Where(x => x.IsVisible())**
```

I have also tried googling searching nodes that appear in the tag list but it just comes up with lots of articles about searching nodes that contain something in their tag list. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.